# How to create an observable of a stream of infinite items

Tags: rx-java2

I have an emitter that keeps emitting items infinitely. How do I turn the stream of items emitted by the emitter to an Observable (or one of its kind) in RxJava 2.

Comment: You could use a subject or wrap the emitter with Observable.create.... can you add code?

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I don't have any code yet, but your comment answers my question. I will post my code once I work out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to stream data? Let's say I am trying to stream data from a database.

```
return Observable.using(
            () -> getQueryConnectionSubscription(sql),

            connectionSubscription -> Observable.create((subscriber) -> {

                ResultSet resultSet = connectionSubscription.getResultSet();
                int rowNumber = 0;
                while (!subscriber.isDisposed() && resultSet.next()) {

                    T row = rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet, rowNumber);
                    subscriber.onNext(row);
                }
                subscriber.onComplete();

            }),

            (queryConnectionSubscription) -> {
                queryConnectionSubscription.close();
            });
```

I am not sure what the source of your data is. But whenever you have data you keep calling subscriber.onNext(data).
If you want the full details checkout the link 
https://www.developerthoughtsonline.com/2019/02/02/streaming-with-reactive-java-and-spring-jdbctemplate/

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I choose Subject over Observable. Below is an example of the code.

```
public class ItemEmitter {
  private BehaviorSubject<Object> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

  public void onEvent(Object item) {
    subject.onNext(item);
  }

  public Flowable<Object> getObservable() {
    return subject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
  }
}
```